# RecyclerView scrolls first inside NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[Layout Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KNsx.png)

NestedScrollView holds everything except top toolbar. Inside NestedScrollView I have ViewPager that contains RecyclerView. I am trying to make so when you trying to scroll RecyclerView NestedScrollView scrolls first to the top and then scroll RecyclerView. But NestedScrollView will start scrolling only when I am at the end of RecyclerView. I was trying to put `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` on a RecyclerView and it seemed to be working but then RecyclerView itself is not scrolling anymore. Any ideas how to achieve scrolling behavior like this? Thanks

**UPDATE**
Here is an xml file of main page

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_inner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView/>

        <TextView/>

        <ImageView/>

        <View/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/profile_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inner_main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                // Some layout before ViewPager

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_tabs_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inner_main_content"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border_top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/dark_text_color_transparent_40"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_tablayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabBackground="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark_text_color"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                    app:tabRippleColor="@color/dark_text_color_transparent_10"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/border_top"
                    app:tabPaddingStart="80dp"
                    app:tabPaddingEnd="80dp"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border_bottom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/dark_text_color_transparent_40"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_tablayout"/>

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/profile_viewpager"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/border_bottom"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is a fragment layout for ViewPager

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you using coordinator layout as root layout? If not then try to use it and set flags for appbar/toolbar to be collapsing toolbar layout so that top portion collapse first and then starts scrolling on main content.

Comment: Please put your layout xml file here

Comment: @Sarah Just updated it with xml files